# What is the best practice to design REST URI for the following use case

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

A user can singup in an application
/users

GET /id get userDetails

POST saveUserDetails

A admin can create events for a user to register

/events

POST saveEvent
PUT /{event-id}  for updating event

DELETE /{event-id} deleting an event

Now, the question is where would you place user to event registration uri?

will it be 
/events/{event-id}/register

or 
/users/{user-id}/events?event-id=xxx

and I also want to get list of the events to which the user has registered

Please help me with better API design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no right answers here, so I'll just throw in the hat the patterns that I would probably use:

```
POST /user    - register a new user
GET /user/:id - Get user info
PUT /user/:id - Update user info

POST /event       - create an event
PUT /event/:id    - Update an event
GET /event/:id    - Get event details
DELETE /event/:id - Delete event

GET /event/:id/attendees - Get list of attendees
POST /event/:id/attendees - Add user to list of attendees

GET /user/:id/event - Get list of events that user is attendee of
```

Answer (score 1):

The main goal is to register to an event. Then you should start with `/events`

This is why `/events/{event-id}/register` looks fine to me.

Comment: I also want to get a list of all the events to which the user has registered
How shall i model that?

users/{user-id}/events?

Comment: `/events/registered/{user-id}`

Comment: this leads to ambiguity
where user-id can be assumed as event-id to get the list of users registered to the particular event

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways by which you can achieve this but what I see as the best practice is that you should be able to understand from the URL itself that what you're trying to achieve.

For example,
Admin wants to create an event:

> POST: {basePath}/a/events or {basePath}/admin/events

- a | admin: defines that this action is being performed by an Admin
- events: defines that operation is being performed on events entity

Now User wants to register for the event, hence

> POST: {basePath}/u/events/{eventId} or {basePath}/user/events/{eventId}

- u | user: defines that this action is being performed by the User
- events: defines that operation is being performed on events entity. Which can be multiple entities hence adding `eventId` in the path variable to define which you need to register.

now in the above example, I am assuming you can get the User details in the request 
 or capture it from the session but if that is not the case you want to follow then you might need to use below example (assuming path variable is the only option for you to get the User context)

> POST: {basePath}/u/{Id}/events/{eventId} or {basePath}/users/{userId}/events/{eventId}

You can read more [here](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/) about naming guide if you like.